# Ubuntu couldn't detect my scanner

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu 16.04, GNOME
Don't know why, but Simple Scan stoped working - firstly, the error "no devices was found", after reinstalling last version of hplip and configuring this problem was solved.
But still after trying to press Scan button, or run scanimage -L infinite waiting is appeared (with animation of moving circles in Simple Scan).
I've googled really a lot, but nothing works.
lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 03f0:042a Hewlett-Packard LaserJet M1132 MFP
```

sane-find-scanner:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x042a [HP LaserJet Professional M1132 MFP]) at libusb:003:011
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

So, what can I do?
/etc/hp/hplip.conf doesn't contain any interesting information, as I could see.

Comment: You are *much* more likely to get an answer on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: or maybe superuser

Comment: I've tried to check owner of configuration files - it's me, not root. And yeah, AskUbuntu is a right place, thanks